# Normalize or denormalize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models:

- Country name:string
- State name:string, country:references
- City name:string, state:references

I have model:

- User name:string, surname:string, city:references, ...

Should i keep in this model references to state and country too, or keep only references to city model?

What solution is better?
Trafic on site is not so high.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends entire on your use-cases.  If you have a need to send mail to the address in question, then you most likely want a very consistent address.  Or maybe it's just information for other users to know.

I live in a city called "Newton", but my actual postal address calls it "Newton Centre", but most of us would write it as "Newton Center".  Depending on how this data is used in my app, I might choose to let users enter their city, perhaps using your existing list as a way to help with auto-complete or something.  If you don't have all cities that your users may live in in your database, or if there are errors, then it's a pain for users to deal with.  There are many ways to deal with this, but they all trade off usability for consistency of data.

If you have the three models already and they are populated, then maybe that's the way to go, and having a properly normalized data model (like this) is always my first instinct.  However this is an special situation.  Particularly with state (and perhaps province) and country, there are established ISO standard codes that you can store in a hash in your code, and just store the ISO code in your database.  There are a number of gems that provide these references.

I am almost always one who would say "normalized your database", but this may be a case where for city, state/province, country (and even postal code) you may decide to not have database-backed models.  I think this is how most "typical" applications would handle addresses.